# Magento Validate Form Only Certain Fields

Tags: validation, forms, magento, prototypejs

I have a function to validate **all fields** in a form:

```
validateForm: function() {
    var validator = new Validation(this.form);
    validator.validate();
}
```

There are two controls. **First control** need to validate **only a,b,c fields**. **Second control** need to validate only **d,e,f fields**. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To validate only a certain field, you can use:

```
Validation.validate(document.getElementById(id));
```

Comment: what is `Validation` ?

Comment: @Xiaokun Validation is the prototype class you will find in js/prototype/validation.js